# How to create a UiTableView of balloons like iOS widgets - Swift 3/Xcode 8

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, widget, balloon

I want to create a list of events in my application and I think this would be a perfect look, but I have no idea how to do it. 
Can anybody help me?
Thanks!!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the following method
1) in the interface builder drag a new UITableViewCell
2) Set the contentView and background of tableview to UIColor.clear / UIColor.clearColor();

2) dragIn a view and adjust the size as per requirement
(This will act as container View i.e the bigger balloon)
3) now select background colour to white and change opacity to 85 - 90 %
this will give you the desired color

4) Add Label o top and select the same background colour and the opacity as 50 %  as main view and as there is a difference in opacity of 2 containers you will get the desired effect

5) Connect an outlet connection of the mainView and Label

6) set corner radius to view and and label

```
self.mainView.layer.cornerRadius = 10; // or anything as per requirement
```

AND

```
self.label.layer.cornerRadius = 10; // run it now to adjust the corner radius
```